# why does the Compiler complain in Xcode 6 beta 3 using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am reading a 2048 project written in Swift, I am using Xcode beta 3.

Here is a closure in Swift, with `direction` being a `MoveDirection`

```
let coordinateGenerator: (Int) -> [(Int, Int)] = { (iteration: Int) -> [(Int, Int)] in
  let buffer = Array<(Int, Int)>(count:self.dimension, repeatedValue: (0, 0))
  for i in 0..<self.dimension {
    switch direction {
    case .Up: buffer[i] = (i, iteration)
    case .Down: buffer[i] = (self.dimension - i - 1, iteration)
    case .Left: buffer[i] = (iteration, i)
    case .Right: buffer[i] = (iteration, self.dimension - i - 1)
    }
  }
  return buffer
}
```

the `MoveDirection` enum is given below:

```
enum MoveDirection {
    case Up
    case Down
    case Left
    case Right
}
```

Xcode beta 3 gives the following errors :

[image]

is it just a beta 3 problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that this is just *very* poor error reporting, and that the actual error is that you're mutating an immutable array. Try changing it to:

```
var buffer = [(Int, Int)](...
```

Instead of using let.

Comment: changing `buffer` to `var` worked, but the the compiler doesn't like `[(Int, Int)]`

Comment: yap that's what I am using now, Thanks :)

Comment: The OP's code would have worked before beta 3, since immutable arrays in betas 1 & 2 could still have their contents changed, just not their length. The initialization above creates an array of the correct size full of zeroed tuples, so it wasn't being mutated by the old definition. Beta 3 brought truly immutable arrays, which is why you need to declare `buffer` as a variable.